# Upgrading SharePoint 2013 search service application Analytics Reporting Database to SharePoint 2016 - facing InvalidData error

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, searchserviceapplication

I'm getting the below error while trying to add the Analytics Reporting Database to the restored SharePoint server search service application in SharePoint 2016.

I have restored the search service application in SharePoint 2016 using the backed up SharePoint search Administration Database from SharePoint 2013 successfully and while trying to add the Analytics Reporting Database using the below Powershell commands :

```
 $ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Identity "Search Service Application"    
    Add-SPServerScaleOutDatabase -ServiceApplication $ssa -DatabaseServer "DBServer" -DatabaseName "SP_Search_AnalyticsReportingStore"
    $temp = Get-SPServerScaleOutDatabase -ServiceApplication $ssa
    Remove-SPServerScaleOutDatabase -ServiceApplication $ssa -Database $temp[0]
```

it throws the below error message :

```
Add-SPServerScaleOutDatabase : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-SPServerScaleOutDatabase -ServiceApplication $ssa -DatabaseServer ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Offic...caleOutDatabase:SPCmdletAddScaleOutDatabase) [Add-SPServerScaleOutDatabase], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SPCmdletAddScaleOutDatabase
```

as part of troubleshooting we are getting below errors in ULS logs:

**The configuration database was queried for a non-existent object with the id 47982425-24d8-4982-946f-b51f33a2ef95. Most commonly, this is caused by removing an SPFeatureDefinition without writing upgrade code to remove references to the feature from each site.  4521e9a0-05ea-d0d1-d530-d508e9ff8617**
10/30/2023 12:26:01.76  PowerShell_ISE.exe  0x152C  SharePoint Foundation           Config DB                       a6m43   Medium  Querying the DB for Name:[FeatureDefinition/15/47982425-24d8-4982-946f-b51f33a2ef95] of 54bf570b-1578-49aa-a7b1-3423acc15d1d with type:Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition  4521e9a0-05ea-d0d1-d530-d508e9ff8617
10/30/2023 12:26:01.76  PowerShell_ISE.exe  0x152C  SharePoint Foundation           Config DB                       a6m43   Medium  Querying the DB for Name:[FeatureDefinition/14/47982425-24d8-4982-946f-b51f33a2ef95] of 54bf570b-1578-49aa-a7b1-3423acc15d1d with type:Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition  4521e9a0-05ea-d0d1-d530-d508e9ff8617
10/30/2023 12:26:01.76  PowerShell_ISE.exe  0x152C  SharePoint Foundation           Upgrade                         ajyi8   Monitorable Unexpected exception thrown in upgrade session: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean recursively)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDatabase.Upgrade(Boolean recursively)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPManager.RunUpgradeSession(Object lockObject, IUpgradable iup, SPUpgradeOperationFlags upgradeOperationFlags). 4521e9a0-05ea-d0d1-d530-d508e9ff8617

How to solve this issue and add the Analytics Reporting Database successfully.